# Cannot find namespace when declaring a module

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my React/TS project I have declared a module to hold some definitions in a `d.ts` File

```
declare module myapp.booksdirectory {
    interface IData {
        BookName: string;
    }
}
```

But everytime I reference it in a tsx file like `myapp.booksdirectory.IData` I get an error saying `[ts] Cannot find namespace 'myapp'`.

Here's my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react",
        "moduleResolution": "node", 
        "declaration": false,
        "lib": [
            "es5", 
            "dom"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*",
        "./Typings/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Note that my `d.ts` file sits inside the `Typings` folder.

Comment: This could happen if your `.d.ts` file has a `.ts` file alongside it with the same name (causing it to be ignored) or if it contains an import or export (causing it to be treated as an external module).  If that isn't it, I don't know what the problem is and you may have to minimize the example yourself by deleting files until either the problem goes away or you are left with nothing confidential and can publish the source tree.

Comment: Turns out all i needed to do was close and reopen VS Code. FML.